# ¿Por qué no puedo ver mi gráfica en django utilizando chartit?

Tags: python, django, highcharts

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en django. Utilizo chartit para crear una gráfica de líneas. Instalé `django-chartit`, `django-highcharts` y `django-jquery`.

Pongo chartit en `INSTALLED APPS`. Al ejecutar el proyecto, no me marca ningún error pero no logro ver la gráfica. Me gustaría que pudieran ayudarme.

Este es mi código de `views.py`:

```
from chartit import DataPool, Chart
from chartit.chartdata import DataPool

#vista de la gráfica
def line(request):
    ds = DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': Proyecto.objects.all()},
          'terms': [
            'id_proyecto',
            'id_usuario', 
            'id_empresa']}
         ])

    cht = Chart(
            datasource = ds, 
            series_options = 
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'line',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'id_proyecto': [
                    'id_usuario',
                    'id_empresa']
                  }}],
            chart_options = 
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Contenido de proyectos'},
               'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Número de Proyecto '}}})

    return render_to_response('graph.html', {'chartmere':cht})
```

en `graph.html` tengo lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>

{% load chartit %}
 {{ chartmere|load_charts:"container" }}   
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'> Aquí va la gráfica </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error en la consola de Python?, ¿te sale algún error en la consola JS del navegador?

Comment: Hola, no, no marca ningún error, pero no se visualiza nada en pantalla

Comment: Hola, no marca ningún error, pero no se visualiza nada en pantalla.

Comment: Hay tres cosas para chequear. 1.) importa jquery antes de highcharts en `graph.html`. Esto es un requisito de highcharts. 2.) Si no lo hiciste, corre `python manage.py collectstatic`. 3.) Anade `{% load staticfiles %}` arriba de `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Come te parece la pagina despues de estes cambios?